# Mixed tense "In this case, it is killing my blood platelets, and they fell to a dangerously low level."

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

> I have been diagnosed with an auto-immune disease, meaning that my
> immune system will act on its own and attack my own body. In this
> case, it is killing my blood platelets, and they ***fell*** to a dangerously
> low level. I also started to notice red dots on my limbs.   
> Therefore, I tried to set up an appointment with a doctor on a
> Saturday, but the closest Saturday was not a convenient time because I
> had to go to school to teach to make up classes for Monday. Thus I
> scheduled an appointment one week later, and at that point I wasn’t
> taking any medication.    By the time that I saw the doctor, my blood
> platelets had dropped to a critical point, so the doctor gave me a
> prescription and arranged a follow-up appointment the next Saturday.
> If the blood platelets show improvement, we will continue this
> prescription; but if there are no signs of improvement, then the
> doctor will prescribe other medications for me.

In this narrative I wrote, ***Fell*** suddenly becomes simple past. I might have used ***have fallen*** to be consistent.

Should I go for consistency in tense?

Comment: Judging from the subsequent narrative, this must have happened some time ago, so I suggest you say "One day they fell..." or "Some weeks ago, they fell...". I would only use _have fallen_ if the drop in level occurred recently.

Comment: There's a shift in tense anyway: "... have been diagnosed ... is killing ... [they fell] ... I started to notice ... I set up an appointment ...." Yes, right at the word in question you transition from talking about the present to the past, so the recommendation to specify the time frame is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentences can use mixed tenses when talking about mixed situations, such as present reports of past events.  There is no rule against this use  of "fell" but it does seem to me to break the flow of the sentence,

This is compounded in my view by another issue. It was not the platelets that fell; platelets don't have a level. It was the platelet count or number of platelets that fell. The suggestion in comments by Kate Bunting
to specify a time period is a good one. So something like:

> In this case, it is killing my blood platelets, and last month my platelet count fell to a dangerously low level.

or one could write:

> In this case, it is killing my blood platelets, and that caused my platelet count to fall to a dangerously low level.

Both of these smooth the change of tense, in my view, as well as providing additional information to the reader.

Comment: 'caused' still suddenly changed to past tense. Something that is happening now caused an action in the past, which disconerts me. Maybe this is how English is, and I shouldn't think too much about it?

Comment: In this case, it is killing my blood platelets, and that has caused my platelet count to fall to a dangerously low level.

   Do you think 'has caused' is better here, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Something that _has been happening gradually for some time_ caused an event in the past. When you saw the doctor, you would have said "My blood platelet level _has fallen_.  But now you are telling the story with details of various things that have happened since the day you noticed that the level _had fallen_.